# How to use findElements method with implicit waiting?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, findelement

In the method document it's written:

> When implicitly waiting, this method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout is reached

As i see (please fix me if i'm wrong), when the method find one element it returns it without searching the others.
So what is the advantage of using this method upon using **findElement** method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findElements` method returns a **list** of web elements matching the passed locator while `findElement` method will always return a **single** web element.
Also in many cases you are applying `findElement` and `findElements` methods on already fully loaded page. In this case `findElements` will return you a list of **All** the web elements matching the passed locator.
However in order to get all the matching elements in loading page you can't effectively use `findElements` with *implicit wait*.
*Expected conditions* implementing *explicit wait* should be used instead.
In case you know the exact amount of elements matching the passed locator presented on that page you can use this method:

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(element, expectedElementsAmount))
```

And in case you know that it should be at least some known amount of elements you can use this method:

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(element, expectedElementsAmount))
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather individually, you need to read the line in it's entire context.

> - [*findElements()*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)):
>   Find all elements within the current page using the given mechanism.
>   This method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the
>   time of execution. When implicitly waiting, this method will return as
>   soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will
>   return an empty list if the timeout is reached.

Here, *more than 0 items* implies ***greater then 0*** i.e. `n > 0` but definitely find all elements within the current page till the timeout is reached.

Comment: This is definitely a wrong answer! Once at least one element matching the passed locator is detected `findElements` method will return the caught matching elements and will NOT wait till the defined timeout!

Comment: @DebanjabB, sorry but i can't understand your answer. Can you explain the sentence *Here, more than 0 items implies greater then 0 i.e. n > 0 but definitely find all elements within the current page till the timeout is reached.* in another way?